# Get the entry directory as a string in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a Windows software using Tkinter from Python, the purpose of this app is to move specific types of files to a specified directory.
But the error comes here, it looks like that my move function ins't getting my entry text and also the extension text, so thats why I think there is the error, the code is here....

```
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import os
import shutil


def input_source():
    input_path = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()
    input_entry.delete(1, tk.END)  # Remove current text in entry
    input_entry.insert(0, input_path)  # Insert the 'path'


def output():
    output_path = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()
    output_entry.delete(1, tk.END)  # Remove current text in entry
    output_entry.insert(0, output_path)  # Insert the 'path'


def move():

    files = os.listdir(input_entry.get())
    for file in files:  # for every file in the source directory
        file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)  # lets split the name of the file and its extension
        if extension == f".{file_extension.get()}":  # knowing what type of extension or type of file, lets just move
            # those
            # files to the new directory
            shutil.move(f"{input_entry.get()}/{file}", output_entry.get())

        else:  # if there are any files with that extension, lets just pass\skip\terminate the process
            pass


master = tk.Tk()

top_frame = tk.Frame(master)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(master)
line = tk.Frame(master, height=1, width=400, bg="grey80", relief='groove')

# input path
input_path = tk.Label(top_frame, text="Input File Path:")
input_entry = tk.Entry(top_frame, text="", width=40)
browse1 = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Browse", command=input_source)

# output path
output_path = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="Output File Path:")
output_entry = tk.Entry(bottom_frame, text="", width=40)
browse2 = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Browse", command=output)


# File extension
file_extension_ = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="File type:")
file_extension = tk.Entry(bottom_frame, text="", width=40)
file_extension.insert(0, 'Type file extension: .')

move = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Move!', command=move)

top_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP)
line.pack(pady=10)
bottom_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

input_path.pack(pady=5)
input_entry.pack(pady=5)
browse1.pack(pady=5)

output_path.pack(pady=5)
output_entry.pack(pady=5)
browse2.pack(pady=5)

file_extension.pack(pady=5)
file_extension.pack(pady=5)

move.pack(pady=20, fill=tk.X)


master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You mention an error. What is the error?

Comment: Can you copy the exact error that you get so we can check it out?

Comment: The error doesn't appear, but there is an error, because files don't move from the input to the output directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify this and it should work. If you're just trying to move files to the typed path, why not do it this way?

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
root.title("File Mover")

def move_file():
   firstpath = entry1.get()
   secondpath = entry2.get()
   os.replace(firstpath, secondpath)

label1 = Label(text="Enter File Directory to Move")
label2 = Label(text="Enter New File Directory")

entry1 = Entry(width=20, justify="center")
entry2 = Entry(width=20, justify="center")

button = Button(text="Move File", command=move_file)


label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1,column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

this requires they include the name of the file in the path, but I guarantee that it will get the text, and that it works moving the files on my machine.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of using os.replace(firstpath, secondpath), it would be better using from the shutil module: shutil.move(first, second)

Comment: If you'd like, I can research shutil, I just like the os command cause it's simple, clean, and comes base with python without having to pip install any new modules

Comment: Well cool, guess I learnt something today too. I'm just glad I could help.